# Youtube Comments API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

in facebook by adding this tag we can get comments,replies and can reply:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{url}" data-version="v2.3"></div>
```

is there any simple way as facebook comment plugin in YouTube?we can get comments by js but for chatting enviroment we must concentrate every detail:

```
1.like,dislike answers
2.reply unswers
3.user can edit his/her answer  etc etc.
```